# how to change components value or color like Text using id in a function?

Tags: react-native

I want to change Text component value but I don't want to use state because my Text or other components are unique and they made whit a loop and result comes from PHP and MySQL

```
`import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

class MyAppList extends Component {
UserOrderBasket = (ProductId)=>{}

   render() {
         return (
              <View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                         <Text id='amir' style={{ flex:0, width:40, textAlign:'center' }}>
                                    this text will be change
                          </Text>
                          <Button icon transparent style={{width:36,padding:0}} onPress= 
                                    {this.UserOrderBasket.bind(this,1)}>
                              <Text>Change Text</Text>
                         </Button>
              </View>
         )
   }
}

`
```

I want users to press the button and using the UserOrderBasket function change the text like do this in javascript: `

```
function UserOrderBasket (ProductId){
document.getElementById('amir').inneHtml="some text or elemnt put here";
}
```

`

Is that possible ???
please help me if it is possible I really need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is feasible, but not React's recommended approach. In react, the Virtual DOM is used extensively, whereas for your case, you are using the DOM directly.

[image]

The recommended approach is still using state/props as the medium. Your UserOrderBasket() function changes the state, and your text gets updated automatically.

Comment: In the following link you can find React's State and Lifecycle system: 
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Just for more detailed informations about the hint with states you gave :)